Nativewind on ReactNative Expo working but only accepting single option
New Boilerplate project React TS Expo project compiling but I cant apply multiple native wind options
using tabs index.tsx rather than App.tsx
for example i can do
<Text className="text-3xl">Edit app/index2.tsx to edit this screen.</Text> 
but i cant do below or any variation
<Text className="text-3xl items-center">Edit app/index2.tsx to edit this screen.</Text>
Anybody come across this - I would expect it not to work
followed expo nativewind guide and installed 3.3.2 tailwind -
config line
content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./app/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
babel line
plugins: ["nativewind/babel"],
Tried to use 49 template and nativewind 402 and variations -
any advice appreciated

Do you have nativewind-env.d.ts set up? https://www.nativewind.dev/getting-started/typescript

Thanks I just found the reference on another post as well . Where was that in expo setup instructions ? Would have saved me a lot of time . Appreciate the response

My own fault for not reading the full article but saying that I tried that but still stuck in single loop after adding in the nativewind-env.d.ts with '/// '  file and allowing in tsconfig

I’ve tried different versions 2 and 4 and with  different templates . Is there a nativewind guide set up that works with sdk51 . I can get a clean build with no plug-in error but it never loads nativewind style . How does it still process flex-1 class name .from standard css ? Thanks

Can you try making a new project and then re-setup nativewind? Maybe something wonky has happened to some node_modules or something

thanks Ive been days at it now. Would you have a guide you followed for latest nativewind you could recommend. Whats confusing me is it seems to accept a view classname option in the singular but not as a multi option string like flex-1 items-center etc- no errors

Thats really weird. For me, installing it was so smooth that I dont really remember doing it. I just followed the guide here https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/expo. Thats why im wondering if its something wonky like node_modules being wrong or your typescript config being nonstandard

cuz for me when I look at the className prop type it says its a string; so rather the string have spaces or not  shouldnt be throwing an error

Is there a nativewind typescript eslint plugin that you are using?

I created an new project where I dont get any errors https://github.com/PhantomSpook/nativewindexpodemo

could below be my issue. I got it when i did npx expo start -am i running too new a node? - WARNING: The legacy expo-cli does not support Node +17. Migrate to the new local Expo CLI: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421. running npm install now but i am guessing it will cause issue on your project but lets see

ran ok once i did npm install -just tested by creating a new page in app but when i remove stylesheet and add classname to view it does not seem to be loading-im doing something wrong just cant figure out what

i installed latest nodejs on a separate win 10 PC - create-expo-app@latest and followed https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/expo to the T including nativewind-env.d.ts- I got to same exact point with it seeing like  plugin is not loaded or not presenting in VSCode. ill do a video of my install and maybe someone might see something im doing wrong. Thanks PhantomSpooks much appreciate the advise

https://electro.bitrix24.eu/~aOEcp    This is my file transfer of 20mb video file showing my journey - pm me f you want to double check

Had some success with adding following to my tsx with style 'import { NativeWindStyleSheet } from "nativewind";
NativeWindStyleSheet.setOutput({
default: "native",
});' thanks all for advice
